# How to disable scroll on refresh

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

i have flatlist with refreshcontrol, everything is fine, just one problem, on refresh, it automatically scrolls to the top of the page, which is something i do not want, here is the video, how do i make flatlist stay on the same height (y) on refresh?

(i can't put up iframe so here's youtube link: https://youtube.com/shorts/I9zTh8LwMf4?feature=share)

```js
<FlatList
  style={styles.flatList}
  contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContent}
  keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
  renderItem={renderItem}
  data={data}
  ref={flatListRef}
  refreshControl={
    <RefreshControl
      style={{ transform: [{ scale: 0.8 }] }}
      refreshing={isRefreshing}
      onRefresh={async () => {
        setRefreshing(true);
        //fetch
        setRefreshing(false);
      }}
    />
  }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the component has an [enabled boolean prop](https://reactnative.dev/docs/refreshcontrol#enabled-android) but this doesn't work on ios. As a hack solution I only return the refresh component if it should be enabled.

Notice the `!!onRefresh` used to evaluate if there should be refreshing allowed.

```js
<ScrollView
  contentContainerStyle={wrapperStyles}
  nestedScrollEnabled={true}
  scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
  scrollIndicatorInsets={{ right: Number.MIN_VALUE }}
  ref={scrollRef}
  refreshControl={
    !!onRefresh ? (
      <RefreshControl
        onRefresh={handleRefresh}
        refreshing={refresh}
        size={30}
        tintColor={theme.colors.black}
      />
    ) : undefined
  }
  {...props}
>
  {children}
</ScrollView>
```